# 404 Not Found error in my Laravel Sanctum

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-10, laravel-sanctum

I'm new in Laravel PHP and I have a question. I'm currently using the **Laravel Sanctum** package and I'm having a problem in regards of the login authentication and route protection that I created.

So like,  I'm watching youtube tutorials that saves api tokens from registration, login, and logout which saves in the personal_access_token. But the problem is they only show it working in postman, so I tried recreating it but in user actions in my webpage.

After multiple attempts I managed to create registration API tokens for my **Admin** and **Faculty** models, I also managed to create login tokens (but based on the json format used to postman), but when I removed it and used this code:

```
    public function login(LoginAdminRequest $request)
    {
        $credentials = request()->validate([
            'AdminUsername' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        if (Auth::guard('admins')->attempt($credentials)) {
            $admins = Admin::where('AdminUsername', $request->AdminUsername)->first();
            $admins->createToken('Login Token of ' . $admins->AdminUsername)->plainTextToken;
            Auth::guard('admins')->user()->update(['last_used_at' => now()]);
            return Redirect::to('admindashboard');
        }

        return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['AdminUsername' => 'Invalid credentials']);
    }
```

This is the method I used in the postman:

```
public function login(LoginAdminRequest $request)
{
    // Validation is automatically handled by the LoginAdminRequest
    
    $credentials = $request->only('AdminUsername', 'password');

    if (!Auth::guard('admins')->attempt($credentials)) {
        return $this->error('', 'Credentials do not match...', 401);
    }

    $admins = Admin::where('AdminUsername', $request->AdminUsername)->first();

    return $this->success([
        'admins' => $admins,
        'token' => $admins->createToken('Login Token of ' . $admins->AdminUsername)->plainTextToken
        
    ]);
}
```

And this is the route protection I used when testing in the postman:

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('admindashboard', [AuthController::class, 'adminView'])->name('adminhome');
    Route::post('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
});
```

And it works fine in postman because it uses **BearerToken** to authorize the api token I used in the login via postman as shown here:
[Me using the personal_access_token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz5fh.png)

But when I used the first method above it returns 404 Not found instead, but when I checked my **personal_access_token**, a new api token was created, but the **last_used_at** were still empty, so like I created a token for login, but the website didnt authorize that token so I didn't get access to my webpage without postman.

Here are the other things I used for this:

> LoginAdminRequest.php (a custom request):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class LoginAdminRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }


    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'AdminUsername' => ['required', 'string', 'min:5'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:5']
        ];
    }
}
```

> Custom success method from my custom HttpResponse:

```
?php

namespace App\Trait;

trait HttpResponse {
    protected function success($data, $message=null, $code=200)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'Request was successful!',
            'message' => $message,
            'data' => $data
        ], $code); 
    }
}
```

> Admin model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $primaryKey = 'AdminID';

    protected $fillable = [
        'AdminUsername',
        'AdminEmail',
        'password',
    ];
}
```

> my auth.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],

        'faculties' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'faculties',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
            'table' => 'admins',
        ],

        'faculties' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Faculty::class,
            'table' => 'faculties',
        ],
        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expiry time is the number of minutes that each reset token will be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    | The throttle setting is the number of seconds a user must wait before
    | generating more password reset tokens. This prevents the user from
    | quickly generating a very large amount of password reset tokens.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_reset_tokens',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

Comment: what returns a 404? what URL are you trying to reach? this is confusing to follow what you are trying to say you are doing here ... also why are you generating a token if this is for a web interface?

Comment: I basically got 404 error when im trying to access the admindashboard

Comment: which are inside the middleware auth:sanctum

Comment: and what **URL** is that in the browser that is showing a 404 page? also the 'sanctum' guard isn't the same as the 'admins' guard

Comment: when I accessed it using postman it works find, but when I accessed it inside my webpage, it returns 404 Not Found instead

Comment: it returns /admindashboard instead of /api/dashboard because I defined that route inside my api.php

Comment: okay, so why don't you fix that then ... and this isn't an API if you are having users interact with your web application in a web browser directly

Comment: because it was the same even if I define it at web.php

Comment: also im new to it i don't know much

Answer (score 0):

I don't underestand part about (accessing that route in postman), but
Try to cache route and list theme:

```
php artisan route:cache
php artisan route:list
```

Then find your route in list, and then (i think you should another way to redirect), try these:

```
return redirect('/admindashboard');
// or you can your route name
return redirect()->route('adminhome');
```

The other problem in your code is this line, but its not related to 404 response:

```
Auth::guard('admins')->user()->update(['last_used_at' => now()]);
```

you are trying to update user last_used_at field, but i think its token fields